# How do I put 2 columns beside each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to I get the two columns to go beside each other. The first one will have text and the 2nd one will be a list. This is the header section and might have a background image. I'm using bootstrap v3.3.4, HTML5 and CSS3

I have attached an image of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
<section id="about-us" class="about-us">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<div class="block wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration="500ms">
<h2>WE ARE</h2>            
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<div class="block wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration="500ms">
<h2>WE ARE</h2>            
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.about-us {
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: scroll;
color: #fff;
position: relative;
background-position: center;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100vh;
}

.about-us h2 {
font-size: 650%;
font-weight: 400;
margin-bottom: 0px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #666;
}

.about-us .block {
position: relative;
padding: 340px 0px 0px;
z-index: 99;
text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

NEW CODE:

```
<section id="about-us" class="about-us">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3  col-md-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3">
<div class="block wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-   duration="900ms">
<h2>sample</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
<div class="block wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".6s" data-wow-duration="900ms">
<h1>sample</h1>
<h1>sample</h1>
<h1>sample</h1>
<h1>sample</h1>
<h1>sample</h1>
<h1>sample</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.about-us {
background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(18, 172, 234, 0.42), rgba(0, 191, 255,          0.55)),url(background-about-header.png);
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: scroll;
color: #fff;
position: relative;
background-position: center;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100vh;
}

#about-us h1 {
font-size: 400%;
font-weight: 400;
text-transform: none;
color: #fff;
text-align: justify;
margin: auto;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(56, 56, 56, 0.73);
}


.about-us h2 {
font-size: 750%;
font-weight: 400;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
line-height: 80px;
padding-top: 70px;
padding-right: 20%;
margin: auto;
text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px rgba(56, 56, 56, 0.73);
}





#about-us .block {
position: relative;
padding: 205px 0px 0px;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
}
```

Media Query

```
#about-us .block {
padding: 0px;
}

#about-us h1 {
text-align: justify;
margin-left: 20%
}

#about-us h2 {
padding-top: 150px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
margin-left: 10%
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.about-us h1,h2 {
font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:flex` or `display:table` or `display:inline-block` can do this :

---

`display:flex`

```css
.about-us h2 {
/*font-size: 650%;
font-weight: 400;*/
margin-bottom: 0px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #666;
margin:auto;
}
.row,.col-md-6  {
  display:inline-flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.col-md-6 {
flex:1;
  padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<section id="about-us" class="about-us">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="block wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration="500ms">
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="block wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration="500ms">
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

& `display:table`

```css
.about-us h2 {
/*font-size: 650%;
font-weight: 400;*/
margin-bottom: 0px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #666;
margin:auto;
}
.row {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.col-md-6 {display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<section id="about-us" class="about-us">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="block wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration="500ms">
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="block wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration="500ms">
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

&   `display:inline-block`

```css
.about-us h2 {
  /*font-size: 650%;
font-weight: 400;*/
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #666;
  margin: auto;
}
 .col-md-6 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section id="about-us" class="about-us">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="block wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration="500ms">
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="block wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration="500ms">
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
          <h2>WE ARE</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: How do I make this responsive?

Comment: @Classics07 wich method did you pick up ? and what behavior would you expect ? stacking on top each other ? reverse order ?

Comment: I went with the first one. I have figured it out except the columns are aligning to the left instead of centered

Comment: you may use display:flex instead inline-flex; and add flex-wrap:wrap; to allow boxes to break in 2 lines. do you have a better piece of code (content) to see what you have in real (you may fake image & text http://html-ipsum.com http://dummyimage.com or other sites you know

Comment: How do I send it to you?

Comment: you can use http://codepen.io/pen or http://jsfiddle.net to share in your question or build a snippet in the qusetion itself

Comment: I pasted it under NEW CODE in the the question

Comment: i made this http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/oxxLbY , but i deleted on <div class="row"> after h2 sample. CSS updated : height:100vh to min-height 100vh and adde CSS rules for .row